# Use Mountebank copy behavior in multiple stubs

Tags: mountebank

Is it possible to share a variable between Mountebank stubs?

Here's a high level example:

Stub A:

```
{
    "predicates": [
        {
            "matches": {
                "body": "amount=420"
            }
        }
    ],
    "responses": [
        {
            "is": {
                "statusCode": 200
                },
                "body": {
                      "transaction_id": "123456",
                      "amount": 420
                      },
                "_behaviors": {
                  "copy": [{
                   "from": {"query": "transaction_id"},
                   "into": "${TRANSACTION1}",
                   "using": {
                    "method": "regex",
                    "selector": "(?<=transaction_id%5D=).{6}"
                  }
                 }]
              }
```

Stub B:

```
{
    "predicates": [
        {
            "matches": {
                "body": "approved=420"
            }
        }
    ],
    "responses": [
        {
            "is": {
                "statusCode": 200
                },
                "body": {
                      "transaction_id": "${TRANSACTION1}",
                      "amount": 420
                      }
              }
```

The copy _behavior approaches I have tried for Stub B do not seem to recognize the variable specified in Stub A. From the documentation, it seems as though I cannot use copy between these stubs.

Answer (score 1):

As per the developer, this behavior isn't supported at this time. See: https://github.com/bbyars/mountebank/issues/476